# Creating a Calculated Field using date range parameters on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I'm trying to create a calculated field for previous period results based on a set of Date Start and Date End parameters. This is what I have:

{
INCLUDE [Post Category],[Channel]:SUM
(
IF [Date] >= DATE([Date Start])
AND [Date] <= DATE([Date Start])
THEN [Impressions] END
)
}

I tried the code above but it doesn't populate. For example, I have my [Date] set as 1/1/23 to 12/31/23 and my parameters for [Date Start] as 1/1/2022 and [Date End] as 12/31/2022. What am I doing wrong here? I'm assuming the date range I selected aren't counting? not sure where to go from here.
[image of calculated field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMHwn.png)

Comment: Try dropping the whole INCLUDE clause, and even drop the SUM from your calc

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that there doesn't seem to be any reason to use an LOD calculation here. Use the simplest type of calc that fits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a parameter as a date but your parameter should just be a date when created.

Check this documentation on [how to create a filter for start and end date using parameters](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-filter-for-start-and-end-dates-parameters?lang=eng). This will get you a calculated field as a filter, let's call it `[date filter]`.

Modify your calculation to what Alex said in the comments; and just grab the total impressions you want to see, bring it to your worksheet and it will be filtered by the above `[date filter]`.

Answer (score -2):

You're using Date Start twice.

[image]

Comment: i updated the image link but the problem persists with the correct start and end fields.